# How do I remove everything after a certain character in a value in a dictionary for all dictionaries in a group of dictionaries?

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary

My goal is to remove all characters after a certain character in a value from a set of dictionaries.

I have imported a CSV file from my local machine and printed using the following code:

```
import csv
with open('C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\Aug_raw_Page.csv') as csvfile:
    reader=csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

I get a set of directories that look like:

```
{Pageviews_Aug':'145', 'URL':'http://www.domain.com/#fbid=12345'}
```

For any directory that includes a value with `#fbid`, I am trying to removing `#fbid` and any characters that come after that - for all directories where this is true.

I have tried:

```
for key,value in row.items():
       if key == 'URL' and '#' in value or 'fbid' in value
            value.split('#')[0]
            print row
```

Didn't work.

Don't think `rsplit` will work as it removes only whitespace.

Comment: You say `split` or `rsplit` don't work. Why? Can you give a short example?

Answer (score 4):

Fastest way I thought about is using `rsplit()`

```
out = text.rsplit('#fbid')[0]
```

---

Okay, so I'm guessing your problem isn't in removing the text that comes afer the `#` but in getting to that string.

What is 'row'?
I'm guessing it's a dictionnary with a single 'URL' key, am I wrong?

```
 for key,value in row.items():
     if key == 'URL' and '#fbid' in value:
        print value.split('#')[0]
```

---

I don't quite get the whole format of your data.
If you want to edit a single variable in your dictionary, you don't have to iterate through all the items:

```
if 'URL' in row.keys():
    if '#fbid' in row['URL']:
         row['URL'] = row['URL'].rsplit('#fbid')[0]
```

That should work.
But I really think you should copy an example of your whole data (three items would suffice)

Comment: yes. i believe row is the dictionary.  The dictionary has 10 keys.  I just showed URL and Pageviews_Aug in the above example.I run the above and get only values stipulated in the if statement. Need to get back all original directories with only everything past #fbid removed. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> value = 'http://www.domain.com/#fbid=12345'
>>> re.sub(ur'#fbid.*','',value)
'http://www.domain.com/'
>>> value = 'http://www.domain.com/'
>>> re.sub(ur'#fbid.*','',value)
'http://www.domain.com/'
```

---

for your code you could do something like this to get the answer in the same format as before:

```
import csv
with open('C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\Aug_raw_Page.csv') as csvfile:
    reader=csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        row['URL'] = re.sub(ur'#fbid.*','',row['URL'])
        print row
```

Comment: just so you know .* means any number of any character

Comment: I think this worked! I need to get better with regex.  Thanks dabhand.

Answer (score 0):

given your sample code, it looks to you that don't work because you don't save the result of `value.split('#')[0]`, do something like

```
for key,value in row.items():
    if key == 'URL' and '#' in value or 'fbid' in value
        new_value = value.split('#')[0]  # <-- here save the result of split in new_value
        row[key] = new_value             # <-- here update the dict row
 print row                               # instead of print each time, print it once at the end of the operation
```

this can be simplify to

```
if '#fbid' in row['URL']:
    row['URL'] = row['URL'].split('#fbid')[0]
```

because it only check for one key.

example

```
>>> row={'Pageviews_Aug':'145', 'URL':'http://www.domain.com/#fbid=12345'}
>>> if "#fbid" in row["URL"]:
        row["URL"] = row['URL'].split("#fbid")[0]


>>> row
{'Pageviews_Aug': '145', 'URL': 'http://www.domain.com/'}
>>>
```

Comment: hmmm. running this, I get one dictionary back of a number i need returned.  I'm sure this is my issue - just not sure what it is.

Comment: well you want the dictionary back, right? with this only the entry `URL` is modify